# ASP.NET Core 3.1 OData: Cannot Select Entity By Id

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I have an OData endpoint (action method) that returns an `IQueryable` list of items:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Entity> Get()
```

The POCO class has the `[Key]` attribute applied to its id property. It works fine, all entities are returned and I can do filters, etc. But I cannot select an instance by its id, that is:

```
/odata/entity?$filter=Id eq 1   //works
/odata/entity(1)                //does not work
```

Is there any setup that I need to do? I also tried configuring the key in the model:

```
var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
odataBuilder.EntitySet<Student>("Entity").EntityType.HasKey(x => x.Id);
```

But it also dit not work. The only way I can achieve this is by adding an action method specifically for this:

```
public Entity Get(int key)      //works
```

But I was under the impression that this would not be needed, the other action should be enough. Am I wrong?

Comment: For people that search for anwer, why Get by Id doesn't work even with method, check parameter name. It should be "key":
      public Entity Get(int key)      //works
      public Entity Get(int id)      //nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my research and the examples found, I don't think this is possible, e.g., there is always a need for a dedicated method for this.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: use ODataRoutePrefix + ODataRoute because `[Route("api/[controller]")]` can't handle OData `api/todo(10)` for single navigable entity.

To get the OData convention for `api/todo(10)` working:

```cs
            // Startup - Configure()
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(100);
                endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel())
                    .EnableDependencyInjection();
```

```cs
//[Route("odata/[controller]")] // remove this
[ODataPrefix("todo")]           // add this
public class TodoController : ODataController {

        // /odata/todo?$filter=id eq 142
        [EnableQuery] 
        public IQueryable<Todo> Get(
            [FromServices] MyDataContext dataContext)
        {
            return dataContext.Todo;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        [ODataRoute("({id})")] // /odata/todo(142)
        public IActionResult GetByKey(
            [FromODataUri] long id,
            [FromServices] MyDataContext dataContext)
        {
            return Ok(dataContext.Todo.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id));
        }
```

None of the OData samples for ASP.NET Core use `[ODataRoutePrefix]` and `[ODataRoute]` but those are necessary for routing using OData convention `api/todo(10)`.

If you use normal `[Route("api/[controller]")]` on controller and `[Route("({id})"]` on `GetByKey()` then your route is

- `~/api/todo/(10)` - BADBAD
- `~/api/todo(10)`  - GOOD

.. the later is the convention used in many samples including https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/ .

This also seems to break the helper `Created(todo)` used in `POST` samples, because it can't find `api/todo({newId})` route to return in the Location header.

Comment: In 8.0 odata library they seem to favor `todo/10` over todo(10)`, which matches standard REST resource and routes.

Comment: TODO: Test the ability to "chain" expand and filter odata operators via `todo/10` routes in 8.0.